# How to show that $\cos(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}}{ (2n)!} $

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion

We know that cos(x) is infinitely differentiable and the Lagrange remainder $\rightarrow 0$ for all $x$, so the Taylor series indeed produces the function. We also know that
$\cos^{(4k)}(x)=\cos(x)$ at $x=0$ its $1$
$\cos^{(4k+1)}(x)=-\sin(x)$ at $x=0$ its $0$
$\cos^{(4k+2)}(x)=-\cos(x)$ at $x=0$ its $-1$
$\cos^{(4k+3)}(x)=\sin(x)$ at $x=0$ its $0$

Now the question is how do i get that sum from these informations?

Comment: You (should) know that the Taylor series is $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(m)}(0)}{m!}x^m.$$ Now insert the values of $\cos^{(m)} 0$ that you already determined. What do you get?

Comment: I see that we can leave out (4k+1)th and (4k+3)th derivatives and i think i see why we get that sum,but i still don't know how to give exact calculation becouse we would get $$\sum_{4k=0}^\infty {1\over (4k)!}\cdot x^{4k} +  \sum_{4k+2=0}^\infty {1\over (4k+2)!}\cdot x^{4k+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is the Taylor expansion around $0$ of the cosine function.
With $f(x) = \cos(x)$ you just proved that

$\dfrac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}f(x) = (-1)^n$ and $\dfrac{d^{2n+1}}{dx^{2n+1}}f(x) = 0$

Just introduce this in the [Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Definition) definition and you will get your sum.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor's expansion (with $f^n(a) = \left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)\right|_{x=a}$)
$$
f(0+x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^nf^n(0)}{n!}
$$
$\cos(x)$ becomes:
\begin{align*}
\cos(x) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x^{4n}\cdot1}{(4n)!}+\frac{x^{4n+1}\cdot 0}{(4n+1)!}+\frac{x^{4n+2}\cdot(-1)}{(4n+2)!}+\frac{x^{4n+3}\cdot 0}{(4n+3)!} \right)
\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x^{4n}\cdot 1}{(4n)!}+\frac{x^{4n+2}\cdot(-1)}{(4n+2)!}\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x^{2(2n)}\cdot(-1)^{2n}}{(2(2n))!}+\frac{x^{2(2n+1)}\cdot (-1)^{(2n+1)}}{(2(2n+1))!}\right)
\end{align*}
Now, put $2n=m$, to get
$$
\cos(x) = \sum_{m=0,2,4}^{\infty} \left(\frac{x^{2m}.(-1)^{m}}{(2m)!}+\frac{x^{2(m+1)}.(-1)^{(m+1)}}{(2(m+1))!}\right)
$$
Now, the first term uses even powers for $-1$ and second term uses odd. So, this can be rewritten as the required form.

PS: It might be easier to prove using the expansion of $e^{jx}$ and collecting the real part of that.